# Fastest way to obtain a China tourism visa in Hawaii?

Tags: visas, china, hawaii, new-zealand-citizens, honolulu

I am in [Honolulu](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Honolulu) and want to quickly get a tourism visa for mainland [China](https://wikivoyage.org/wiki/China).

What are my options?
I would prefer to avoid flying to [Los Angeles](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Los_Angeles)/[Hong Kong](https://wikivoyage.org/wiki/Hong_Kong) or similar.

Nationality: [New Zealand](https://wikivoyage.org/wiki/New_Zealand)

Comment: I believe many nationalities can get them in Hong Kong, is there any chance you could fly to China via HK and get it before you travel onwards to your destination in China?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many travel agencies that you can give your passport and filled visa application to, and they will apply for the visa for you in person at the appropriate Chinese consulate (in Los Angeles).